# How to re-scale a gltf model so that the transformation scaling is 1?

Tags: animation, rigging, conversion

I want to edit a gltf asset that is rigged such that the geometry is never scaled, i.e. apply the scaling modifier directly to the other 2 transformations and change the scaling of the vertices appropriately to get back the same model.